# HTML Tidy: just find issues and not modify the file

Tags: htmltidy

I am new to HTML Tidy, I just heard of it while checking out options to find HTML tag issues in resource strings. Is there a way to invoke HTML Tidy on a folder of .resx files which could have HTML content? The intent would be to check if HTML tag issues exist. If they exist then report them but not modify the source file.

Since most of the resource file content is not HTML based tags, I would like HTML Tidy not to flag anything without HTML tags as errors. Those resources which have HTML tags and those which have improper tags are my concern.

Answer (score 1):

Tidy reads HTML, XHTML and XML files and writes cleaned up markup. It can be run on any type of file, but cannot ignore errors such as a missing doctype. Use a [[power]shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650689/convert-simple-bash-script-to-powershell) with [findstr/grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473425/grep-like-syntax-with-findstr) to find files with a doctype, then run tidy on that subset.